# jquery pass the click event to onclick property

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following tag:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs userView" onclick="viewUser('+id+')">Se mere</a>
```

Now i want to pass the click event just like you would do with jquery:

```
     $('.checkbox_input').click(function(e)
 {
 })
```

So that i can have the following function

```
    function viewUser(id,event)
{
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();

}
```

Comment: Why would you use inline js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So pass in `event`

```
onclick="viewUser('+id+', event)"
```

Check out [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tebay/1/edit?html,js,output)